# How to fix this pgfplot (5x*e^{-x}+1)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=8,ymax=3,
    smooth,
    restrict y to domain=0:4,
    axis lines = left]
    \addplot[red] {5 * x * 1 / pow(e,x) + 1};   \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: How it looks like]

But that is wrong. This is how it should look like:
[image]

What I need to fix:

1. starting from y = 0 instead of x = 1
2. make the curve go to x = 8 and not just stop in the middle

That is all. I don't want a grid or anything else changed. It would be very nice if you could help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code. This said, why don't you try replacing `xmax=18` with `xmax=12, ymin=-8, xmin=-5`.

Comment: I would use `exp(-x)` instead of `1/pow(e,x)=1/exp(x*ln(e))`,even though `ln(e)=1` (you still have to compute over and over again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always post compilable code, so that people answering has a starting point.

You need the `domain` for which you wish to plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    domain=-1:8,
    xmin=-1, xmax=8,
    ymin=0, ymax=3,
    smooth,
    axis lines = left]
    \addplot[red] {5 * x * 1 / pow(e,x) + 1};   
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: As can be see near the peak, `smooth` does not make it completely smooth. I would add the `samples=100` option to fix this.